FX risk in CDS vs corporate bonds
What is the difference in how one would hedge FX risk of these two positions (from the perspective of EUR investor):

Single name CDS on a specific US corporate bond issuer
(USD denominated) corporate bond of the same issuer


Not sure what you mean. The fx delta of a cash bond is much  larger (face value and coupons), and can be statically hedged with cross-currency swaps.  The fx delta of a CDS, while there's no credit event, is just the mark to market of the swap, so it's much smaller than that of a bond, but you can't predict how that will fluctuate and can't hedge it statically. If there is a credit event, then  a large cash flow in foreign currency will occur.
